# Remove from array of Object if Empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a array of object ,

```
var  arr = [
  {qty_auth: "", resolution: "4", status: "", order: "1495"},
  {qty_sized: "1", resolution: "4", status: "", order: "1485"}
]
```

If first one is empty (ex:qty_auth),want to remove the object from the array on loop. The First one is dynamic key as qt_auth,qty_sized is dynamic

So the output must be

```
var  arr = [
  {qty_sized: "1", resolution: "4", status: "", order: "1495"}
]
```

Comment: That's not a valid javascript array - when you figure that out, look at `Array.filter()`

Comment: For an object in JS, you cannot say for sure which property is first and which is 2nd. You can instead keep a list of properties/attributes, you want to check and then check if these are empty one by one may be.

Comment: You conceptually want to filter the array, so Array.prototype.filter is what you are looking for. The difficult thing is that you want to use a condition based on the first key of the object, which can change from case to case. This is not possible. Javascript objects are defined as unordered key value pairs. When you iterate over object keys the order is implementation dependant. You have no guarantee about the order of object keys.

Comment: So, in order to successfully filter your array, you need to know in advance the name of the keys you want to check in your filter condition (the fuction you provide to Array.prototype.filter). If there are multiple possible keys, you need to check all of them for each object in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), iterate over the array
- In each iteration, check if the current object has a key starting with `qty_`. You can do this using [`Object#keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), and [`String#startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith). If the key exists but its value is empty, return `false`

```js
const arr = [ {qty_auth: "", resolution: "4", status: "", order: "1495"}, {qty_sized: "1", resolution: "4", status: "", order: "1485"} ];

const res = arr.filter(e => {
  const qtyKey = Object.keys(e).find(key => key.startsWith('qty_'));
  if(qtyKey && !e[qtyKey]) return false;
  return true;
});

console.log(res);
```

Note: the key order in javascript objects is undefined.

Comment: what if it is object of object ? @Majed Badawi

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `const arr = { {qty_auth: "", resolution: "4", status: "", order: "1495"}, {qty_sized: "1", resolution: "4", status: "", order: "1485"} };`    in this case how will it work?

Comment: This is not valid json, can you elaborate more

Comment: I am preparing an array like this ` datas[1] = {
            "qty_sized": ",
            "resolution": "5",
            "status": "",
            "order": 1342
        };`   and then  i push array to an object items,  with assign  `Object.assign(mydatadata.items, datas);` Now mydata.items has an array set, from which i need to check if qty_sized is empty then remove and if qty_auth has value keep it .   @Majed Badawi

Comment: can you add ``mydatadata.items`` current value that you need to filter and the expected output to the question?

Comment: No. I updated the flow so based on this i want the answer @Majed

Comment: I have created a new question here,   [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69807312/remove-array-of-object-if-object-inside-is-empty] @Majed

Answer (score 2):

There is not particular sequence in an object in JS, but what you can do is check for the existence and filter out only the object that contain `qty_auth` or `qty_sized` and it should not be empty `""`. You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var arr = [
  { qty_auth: "", resolution: "4", status: "", order: "1495" },
  { qty_sized: "1", resolution: "4", status: "", order: "1485" },
];

const result = arr.filter((o) => o.qty_auth || o.qty_sized);
console.log(result);
```

**EDITED:** If you want to filter the objects which starts with `qty` and which is empty then you can do as:

```js
var arr = [
  { qty_auth: "", resolution: "4", status: "", order: "1495" },
  { qty_sized: "1", resolution: "4", status: "", order: "1485" },
];

const result = arr.filter((o) =>
  Object.keys(o).some((k) => k.startsWith("qty") && o[k])
);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: the object key will be dynamic. How will it be dynamic if i add above code ? @decpk

Comment: dynamic how? I mean If there are 100 properties in an object, then which property to check. There must be some criterion

Comment: If something starts with qty, and that object value is empty

Comment: @ShantalKaula Edited solution

Comment: I have to  check in a condition where its inside an object, for example `items:
0: {qty_approved: "1", resolution: "5", status: "", order_item_id: "1332"}  1: {qty_approved: "", resolution: "5", status: "", order_item_id: "1332"} ` . will the above code work ? @decpk

Comment: @ShantalKaula Yup It will work like a charm

Comment: but its now working for me

Comment: I have created a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69807312/remove-array-of-object-if-object-inside-is-empty

Answer (score 0):

As @EnricoMassone below pointed out, the order of objects entries here, which I iterate once I have my object from the array (the `forEach` loop) might not  be the same as declared, so it may be a controversial method. FYI I check if the first object property is not empty and if so, I add the whole object to the array I return.

```
const removeEmpty = (arr) => {
    const arrToReturn = new Array();

    arr.forEach((obj) => {
        if (Object.entries(obj)[0][1] === '') continue;
        else arrToReturn.push(obj);
    });

    return arrToReturn;
}
```

Comment: I'm quite sure that the order of the object entries is not guaranteed and depends on the Javascript engine being used. Objects in Javascript are defined as unordered collections of key-value pairs. So you can't rely in the order here.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
const filtered = arr.filter(({ qty_auth, qty_sized }) => (qty_auth || qty_sized));
```

Comment: The key is added dynamic which loads from another data.

Comment: this checks, if there is a value for either one of the keys. if they are not set yet, the object will be excluded from `filtered`