# Remove array of object if object inside is empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am preparing an array like this

```
 datas[5] = { "qty_sized": "1", "resolution": "5", "status": "", "order": 1342 };
```

where [5] is dynamic from response.

I have and object mydata and inside that I have a object items.

I push array to  object items, with assign

`Object.assign(mydatadata.items, datas);`

Now mydata.items has an array set,
`

```
items{
1 {qty_auth: "", resolution: "4", status: "", order: "1495"},
5 {qty_sized: "1", resolution: "4", status: "", order: "1485"}
}`
```

Now if  qty_auth: "" , from which i need to check if qty_ is empty then remove the array . So expected output is something like this:
Note: qty_ is dynamic here.

`items{ 5 {qty_sized: "1", resolution: "4", status: "", order: "1485"} }`

and i want to result inside same object mydata.items

I tried something like this

```
const mydatadata.items  = mydata.items.filter((o) =>
            Object.keys(o).some((k) => k.startsWith("qty") && o[k])
);

console.log(result);
```

but its now giving me any output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using [`Object#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), get the key-value pairs of `items`
- Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), iterate over the above array
- In each iteration, check if the current item has a key starting with `qty_` whose value is not empty. You can do this using [`Object#keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), and [`String#startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith).
- Using [`Object#fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), convert the filtered pairs to an object again.

```js
const obj = {
  items: {
    1: {qty_auth: "", resolution: "4", status: "", order: "1495"},
    5: {qty_sized: "1", resolution: "4", status: "", order: "1485"}
  }
};

obj.items = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj.items)
  .filter(([_, item]) =>
    Object.keys(item).some(key => key.startsWith('qty_') && item[key])
  )
);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Code works. But how can i push it into same `mydata.items` . Since i need to push that object set to API? @Majed

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about an array, but using curly brackets instead of square brackets. For filter() to work it would have to look like:

```
mydata = {
   items: [
      {qty_auth: "", resolution: "4", status: "", order: "1495"},
      {qty_sized: "1", resolution: "4", status: "", order: "1485"}
   ]
}
```

Assuming it is an actual array there's still a problem with "const mydatadata.items", or at least it throws an error for me because mydatadata is not initialized. Unless it's a typo and it should be mydata, but then you'd be redeclaring it. So depending on what you want:

```
mydata.items = mydata.items.filter((o) =>
        Object.keys(o).some((k) => k.startsWith("qty") && o[k])
);
```

or

```
let mydatadata = {};
mydatadata.items = mydata.items.filter((o) =>
        Object.keys(o).some((k) => k.startsWith("qty") && o[k])
);
```

Furthermore you're storing the result in mydatadata but you're logging the variable result.
So depending on the previous answer:

```
console.log(mydatadata);
```

or

```
console.log(mydata);
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b57qa82d/

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just be using an array rather than an object. It's not really clear from your question what structure you need as you keep changing the terminology to describe your data. For example: "Now `mydata.items` has an array set" but your code says that it should be object with keys, *not* an array.

So I suggest: get your data in an array, and `filter` it by iterating over each object's entries and checking to see if any of the keys starting with "qty" has a value that isn't an empty string. You can then assign that filtered array to `myObject.items`.

```js
const data = [
{ "qty_sized": "0", "resolution": "5", "status": "", "order": 2 },
{ "qty_auth": "", "resolution": "5", "status": "", "order": 3 },
{ "qty_auth": "1", "resolution": "5", "status": "", "order": 1342 },
{ "qty_sized": "", "resolution": "2", "status": "", "order": 1 },
{ "qty_sized": "1", "resolution": "1", "status": "", "order": 142 }];

const filtered = data.filter(obj => {
  return Object.entries(obj).find(([key, value]) => {
    return key.startsWith('qty') && value;
  });
});

const myObject = { items: filtered };

console.log(myObject);
```

Additional documentation

- [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries)
- [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)